# Convert mysql to T-sql?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

i started doing a project where i need to do a cascating dropdown-list with Country,State,City, i already solved that the thing is, i need to populate my database with countrys citys and states, i already found some cool stuff at the internet, but i cant adapt it to my code, i have 2 choices, i can seed the database or insert it directly with T-Sql, i preffered the second, cause i have a lot of data, and i want that it creates the tables and not just insert data to it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sortname` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=249 ;



INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `sortname`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'AF', 'Afghanistan'),
(2, 'AL', 'Albania'),
(3, 'DZ', 'Algeria'),
(4, 'AS', 'American Samoa'),
(5, 'AD', 'Andorra'),
(6, 'AO', 'Angola'),
(7, 'AI', 'Anguilla'),
(8, 'AQ', 'Antarctica'),
(9, 'AG', 'Antigua And Barbuda'),
(10, 'AR', 'Argentina'),
(11, 'AM', 'Armenia'),
```

this is in mySql but i need this code in T-Sql so i can execute it,i already lost days with trying to do this cant figure out how to solve it, cause i cant find a database already in T-SQL and cant find the right approach to do this :S if someone can give me a hand i appareciate a lot.

Ps:Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `MySQL` code to `T-SQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
  [id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  [sortname] varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  [name] varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ([id])
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT countries ON;

INSERT INTO countries ([id], [sortname], [name]) VALUES
(1, 'AF', 'Afghanistan'),
(2, 'AL', 'Albania'),
(3, 'DZ', 'Algeria'),
(4, 'AS', 'American Samoa'),
(5, 'AD', 'Andorra'),
(6, 'AO', 'Angola'),
(7, 'AI', 'Anguilla'),
(8, 'AQ', 'Antarctica'),
(9, 'AG', 'Antigua And Barbuda'),
(10, 'AR', 'Argentina'),
(11, 'AM', 'Armenia');

SELECT * FROM countries;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/ZXIR52688)**</kbd>

Notes:

- `T-SQL` has `IDENTITY` property instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- You need to quote identifiers with `[]` or `"` instead of backticks
- To insert values to `IDENTITY` column you have to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... ON`

Comment: Just what i need, finally a perfect question thank you very much :D